# My MAC is connected to both Ethernet and Wifi at time,how can i detect from which network is getting acessed

Tags: macos, networking, wifi, ethernet

My MAC is connected to Ethernet and Wifi at a time. Both are different networks. I wanted to know from which interface my system is accessing internet. I want a command to check this. By giving 
`traceroute google.com` , i can get default route, as i know ip addresses of both networks. But the case is how can i detect this in remote machines whose ip addresses are unknown
when i give
`ifconfig`
I see en0 and en1 are assigned with two diff ips and are  active. Even from this i am unable to differentiate.

Comment: Those who give negative marking, should comment below what is bad about it. so that i can improve

Comment: If you hover over a down arrow on a question, it give you the reason for a down vote. The same on all the arrows for up or down votes on questions and answers. I would guess that it is because this is not a programming question that you asked on the SE programming site. There are more appropriate SE sites on which to ask this question.

Comment: It is related to shell scripting. There are many more questions like this on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by following below procedure

1)  `networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder` , by using this we will network service order of MAC, along with interface to which it is connected

2) `route get default | grep interface` gives the currently using interface.

By checking current interface with service order, we can know from which interface our mac is accessing internet